# How to handle multiple notification when app in background or killed in FCM services

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to overwrite new notification with previous one, when app in background. because if app in background then onMessageReceived() not called and i don't want to change payload type in notification.Please give me a better solution with notification and data payload for overwrite new notification with previous one.

Comment: Either app killed or background then you get a notification. It depends on what kind of notification you sent to the app. DataMessage or NotificationMessage

Answer (score 0):

**For Data message:**

If you set the same notification id to the notification then it can replace the previous notification in the notification drawer.

**Example:**

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
```

This will set the id of every new notification to 0 so it will always replace previous notification.

**For Notification message:**

It is not possible to replace previous notification because onMessageReceived() is not called if your app is in background as it is handled by FCM itself.

**Reference:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: Its not working for me.i want to overwrite message when app in background

Comment: i have already used the above code but this works for forground may be, because onMessageReceived() not called in background

Comment: That's because you are receiving Notification message from your server. Server side code needs to send Data message then only onMessageReceived() method will be called in background.

Comment: Oh yes sorry you don't want to change payload type. Then I think it's not possible to replace previous notification.

Comment: no its possible with services and receiver but i don't understand how to use with notification.